# How to resize edit area in JEditorPane?

Tags: java, swing

This is a question about Java and Swing.

I put two JEditorPane into two JScrollPane, and then put the two JScrollPane into a JSplitPane. The problem is that when I drag to resize the JScrollPane, one JEditorPane is extended, but when I drag back, the view shrinks but the edit area doesn't, the horizontal scroll bar appeared.

The code looks like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 600;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

                JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
                JEditorPane preview = new JEditorPane();

                System.out.println(DEFAULT_WIDTH / 2);
                // editor.setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH / 2, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
                editor.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
                // preview.setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH / 2, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
                preview.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));

                final JScrollPane scrollEditor = new JScrollPane(editor);
                final JScrollPane scrollPreview =  new JScrollPane(preview);

                final JSplitPane innerPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, scrollEditor, scrollPreview);
                innerPane.setContinuousLayout(false);
                frame.add(innerPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                innerPane.addPropertyChangeListener(JSplitPane.DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY, new PropertyChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                        editor.setSize(innerPane.getLeftComponent().getBounds().width, editor.getHeight());
                        scrollEditor.setSize(innerPane.getLeftComponent().getBounds().width, editor.getHeight());
                    }
                });
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I try to use JEditorPane.setSize, but it doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You should not need a PropertyChangeListener. The size of the components should change automatically when the divider is moved. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I think the code is clear enough. The problem is the JEditorPane's editable text area, not the JEditorPane Component self. It will adjust with the divider, but If I extend one editor, like drag the divider to the right, and shrink it, like drag back to the left, the component shrink, but the line length in the text area doesn't. So the JEditorPane won't display all characters in one line, I must drag the horizontal scroll bar. Is that clear?

Comment: No the code is NOT clear enough, or I would not have asked for a SSCCE. Since you won't make a little effort to post a SSCCE I guess you really don't want the help.

Comment: I post the question here just for a solution or the help. I revised the code and, now, it's 50 lines short, compilable and well demonstrate the problem I encountered. Waiting for your solution. THANKS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the default implementation of the `Scrollable` interface for your `JEditorPane`. Basically you need to tell the JScrollPane that the width of the JEditorPane should always fit inside the viewport of the scrollpane.

You do this by using code like:

```
JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane()
{
    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

And as I mentioned in my comment you don't need the PropertyChangeListener.

Comment: Wow, great! Thanks a lot, it's certainly what I want! I'll look up the documentation to find out what the Viewport means in Spring. Thanks again.

Comment: @AuBee, `it's certainly what I want` - then don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
final JScrollPane scrollEditor = new JScrollPane(editor, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
final JSplitPane innerPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, true, scrollEditor, scrollPreview);

innerPane.addPropertyChangeListener(JSplitPane.DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY, new PropertyChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

                        editor.setSize(innerPane.getLeftComponent().getBounds().width, editor.getHeight() - 10); // If you want more edge space make 10 to 15 or 20
                        scrollEditor.setSize(innerPane.getLeftComponent().getBounds().width, editor.getHeight());

                    }
                });
```

Comment: If the editor was not wrapped by a scrollPane, I can't scroll it. If the text is longer then the height of the JEditorPane, I couldn't reach the end.

Comment: You mean you only want V scroll? Check the answer updated. you will have vertical scroll now.

Comment: In fact I've already tried the the new solution you post before I add the first comment, the problem didn't solved. Thought horizontal scrollbar didn't appear, the line length is still wider then view width.

Comment: 1. you want the H scrollbar to appear or not ?

you told "line length is still wider then view width" , The updated solution I posted , take care of this problem. It is working here and line length is adjusting as it shrink or enlarge. Tested!

Comment: @LalithJayasinghe, the code doesn't wrap when you shrink the width of the editor pane. Try enlarging the width and the text will unwrap, but then try shrinking the width and the text will no rewrap.

Comment: You should NOT be manually setting the size of a component, that is the job of the layout manager.